# Core Data: Finding Related Objects

Tags: core-data, filter, where-clause, relationship

I am having some issue with understanding of Core Data. In my program there are two entities, say `A` and `B`. They have both references on each other and `A` has a to-many relationship to `B`.

I can have them displayed in TableViewControllers and I can display all `A`s and all `B`s. However, I want to only display all `B`s that belong to a specific `A`, so I'd like to know the Core Data version of a `where` clause. As there are no foreign keys in Core Data, I guess it needs to go via the relationship, right?

I tried it with this:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = nil;
predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"readingEntity.meter=%@",meter];
```

(in the function that I get all `B`s, meter is my `A`).

Anybody out there who can help me on this one?
Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a predicate at all if you already have an `A` object. Instead, you just ask the `A` object for its related `B` objects.

Don't think of Core Data as SQL. It's not. It works differently.

Comment: OK. I guess that's hard. How would I for instance fill a table with specific B only when I get all B's I have? Do I have to pre-sort the array of B beforehand?

Comment: The relationship of `A.bs` will return a set of `B` objects. You can then use a sort descriptor/s to order the set as you wish.

Comment: Thank you - finally I got it somewhen last week.

Comment: @TechZen And how do you handle insertions and deletions of related objects without implementing `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate`?